# How to connect zephyr with Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, karate, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, jira-zephyr

we're using Karate Framwork in our project for API automation so the karate its basically work with a cucumber feature file(Gerkhin keyword based) so is that possible to connect zephyr board with this automation?. As the team requirment is like when the testCase is pass it will automatically update the testCases to pass in the zephyr board.

I tried with zephyr scale app in Jira software but it allows to executs the scripts in Jira only but if we have multiple testCases then how will deal with Jira.

Comment: right now there is no ready-made integration, please see linked answer for other options